# Using .loc and .casefold to filter for dataframe results

Tags: python, pandas

My goal is not to change the dataframe values, I just want to view them as if they were lowercase so that I can use all lowercase words when specifying what to filter, if that makes sense. Is there a way to do this? I want to preserve the case sensitivity of the dataframe but not have to worry about if my `== 'string'` is the right case-type...

I am attempting to apply the casefold method to the column, but am not sure how to approach this as I get an error no matter where I put .casefold()...

```
df.loc[
    (.casefold(df['Record Type']) == 'keyword')
    | .casefold((df['Record Type']) == 'product targeting')
    ]
```

Comment: `df['Record Type'].str.lower() == 'keyword'`

Comment: `df[df['Record Type'].str.lower().isin(['keyword', 'product targeting'])]`

Comment: why doesn't this work when not using .str?   does using .str define the data as a string?